# How to use _self in window.open when a value is included?

Tags: jquery, self, window.open

```
$("#input").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            window.open("search.html?search=" + $("#input").val()); // here is the location
            let searchString = $("#input").val()
            localStorage.setItem("search", JSON.stringify(searchString)); 
        }
    });
```

Its working but opens another tab. It doesnt work without the + $("#input").val());

Tried with both window.location and all the other examples on SO...
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#input").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            window.location = "search.html?search=" + $("#input").val(); // here is the location
            let searchString = $("#input").val()
            localStorage.setItem("search", JSON.stringify(searchString)); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="input"/>
</body>
</html>
```